# Trouble sorting and displaying the latest 5 messages in Django conversation interface

Tags: python, django, sorting

I am working on a Django project where I'm building an interface to display conversations in a table format. However, I'm facing difficulties in sorting the messages so that only the latest 5 received or sent messages are visible.

To limit the messages displayed to 5, I have successfully used the |slice:"5" filter in my HTML template. However, I'm struggling to implement the sorting of messages.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my Django template:

```
        {% for conversation in conversations %}
            <tr>
                <td class="conv-name">
                    <a href="{% url 'detail' conversation.id %}">{{ conversation.name }}</a> <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="conv-check-input" data-conversation-id="{{ conversation.name }}">
                </td>
                {% for message in conversation.conversation.all|slice:"5" %}
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <div class="message">
                                <label title="{{ message.date }}" id="{{ message.id }}-{{ message.origin }}"
                                       origin="{{ message.origin }}">
                                    {# onclick="checked(this)"#}
                                    {{ message.texte }}
                                    {% if message.origin == "Humain" %}
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"
                                               data-message-id="{{ message.id }}"
                                               data-conversation-name="{{ conversation.name }}"
                                        >
                                    {% endif %}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="label">
                                {% for label in message.labels.all %}
                                    <p class="{{ label.color }}">{{ label.name }}</p>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I would like to achieve the following:

- Sort the messages based on their timestamp or any other relevant criterion.
- Display only the latest 5 messages in the conversation table.

I have tried a few approaches, such as using the Django's built-in order_by filter or modifying the queryset in the view, but I haven't been successful so far.

Can anyone please guide me on how to properly sort the messages and limit the display to the latest 5 messages in Django?

My view in views.py file :

```
class ShowMessagesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'interface/show_messages.html'
    context_object_name = "messages"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.order_by('-date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        messages = context['messages']
        # récupérer les utilisateurs correspondant aux messages
        conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(conversation__in=messages).distinct()
        # ajouter les utilisateurs et leurs messages au contexte
        context['conversations'] = conversations
        # récupérer tous les objets Label
        labels = Label.objects.all()
        context['labels'] = labels
        return context
```

And my Model :

```
class Message(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='conversation')
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=False, default="Inconnu")
    texte = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    label = models.ManyToManyField('Label', related_name='labelisation', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.conversation} - {self.texte} - {self.date} - {self.origin}"
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried using Message.objects.order_by('-date') in the view, but it doesn't work. The messages are still not in the same order no matter what I do.
I also try sort with a list :

```
conversation.messages = conversation.conversation.order_by('-date')[:5]
```

or

```
messages = conversation.conversation.order_by('-date')[:5][::-1]
```

or also

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Message.objects.order_by('-date')[:5][::-1]
```

But nothing change